# TinyMCE Editor removing nested tag under anchor tag

Tags: tinymce

I am using TinyMCE editor and I found that text inside a Heading `<H1>` tag which includes an anchor tag (`<A>`) is removed - the anchor link and its contents are getting removed.

What can I do so that the anchor link does not get removed?

You can use the following source code to test result. When we paste below lines in source code.

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <h1>
    <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">
      <font color="blue">This is a New Link.</font>
    </a>
  </h1>
</div>
```

and when we switch to Editor View then the below output we got:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <h1>This is a New Link</h1>
</div>
```

output as below:

[Here is a screenshot of what I get in TinyMCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BO2fD.png)

regard
vik

Comment: I don't get those results using the latest TinyMCE.  Perhaps you can make a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows this using your precise configuration?  Without a precise example of how you have configured TinyMCE it will be hard for anyone here to help you - we really need a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: fiddle with correct example:http://fiddle.tinymce.com/X8faab. Please disregard 1st example.

Comment: The HTML in your fiddle is different from the HTML in your question.  The HTML in the fiddle has a `H1` tag inside a `A` tag - that that is not valid HTML.  I updated the Fiddle to valid HTML and it works fine:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/X8faab/1  If the editor finds invalid HTML it will attempt to correct the broken markup.

Comment: but if we copy and paste the same HTML code in w3schools.com it works fine. Is there any other way so it can accept the HTML ?

Comment: Where are you pasting the same in W3Schools?  Browsers will do their best to render invalid/broken HTML but that does not make the HTML valid.  TinyMCE is trying to make your HTML valid - you cannot turn off that capability.

Comment: well i have fixed it using valid_children but now font tag is getting removed. you can view example here:- http://fiddle.tinymce.com/c9faab